# Ubuntu Server, the server does not turn on

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-interface

I've been trying to configure a home server for a long time, and turn it on via 'WOL s4', however despite having enabled the function from the bios, having seen through the "ethool" command that the wake on lan is active, and when I turn off the server the network card stays on (with steady green LED),
so i think i have successfully activated the wake on lan, however when i hibernate the server and send the magic packet the server does not turn on, i check with tcpdump i see the packets arrive however the server does not turn on, could anyone help me?